# Calculate daily consumption

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization

I've two electric meter. Their values are logged into a MSSQL 2008 database.
Table design is like

```
TimeStamp               MeterID   Count

2013-09-28 00:00:10     BA123     1453.034
2013-09-28 00:01:12     BA123     1454.770
2013-09-28 00:00:14     BB777     2351.000
...
2013-09-28 23:59:50     BA123     1470.120
2013-09-29 00:00:05     BA123     1470.445
```

I need to get the consumption per day, like

```
2013-09-28     BA123     17.411
```

But I've no idea how to realize this?

Edit: "Count" is a consecutive value

Comment: How did you get the number `17.411` out of all the records shown above? What exactly are you looking for? The `SUM` of the records by day?

Comment: `select timestamp,max(count)-min(count) as reading from table group by timestamp`

Comment: @neoistheone: Difference between Minimum of each day (1470.445-1453.034)

Comment: @neoistheone: i like to create a diagram with the daily power consumption within a query interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `CAST` your TimeStamp column to `DATE` and group it:

```
WITH    SampleData  AS
(
        SELECT  [TimeStamp], [MeterID], [Count]
        FROM    (   VALUES
                    ('2013-09-28 00:00:10', 'BA123', 1453.034),
                    ('2013-09-28 00:01:12', 'BA123', 1454.770),
                    ('2013-09-28 00:00:14', 'BB777', 2351.000),
                    ('2013-09-28 23:59:50', 'BA123', 1470.120),
                    ('2013-09-29 00:00:05', 'BA123', 1470.445)
                )   AS SampleData([TimeStamp], [MeterID], [Count])
)
SELECT      MeterId, CAST([TimeStamp] AS DATE) AS [DateConsumption],
            MAX([Count]) - MIN([Count]) AS [CountConsumption]
FROM        SampleData
GROUP BY    MeterID, CAST([TimeStamp] AS DATE)
--WITH ROLLUP
```